# Protocol subclassing and conformance

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, llvm

Given

```
@protocol Response <NSObject>
@end

@protocol DataResponse <Response>
@end

@interface ListUsersResponse : NSObject <DataResponse>
@end

@interface RequestExecutor : NSObject
+(id<Response>) execute: (id<Request>) request receptor: (Class) model;
@end

ListUsersRequest * request = [self buildListUsersRequest];
ListUsersResponse * result = [RequestExecutor execute:request receptor:[ListUsersResponse class]];
```

I get an `Initializing 'ListUsersResponse *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'id<Response>'` error. Why is that? Cant the compiler detect protocol conformance? How to solve it?

Comment: You get an error or a warning ? I think adding a cast should solve this : `ListUsersResponse * result = (ListUserResponse *)[RequestExecutor execute:request receptor:[ListUsersResponse class]]`. PS : you meant `+(id<Response>) execute: (id<Request>) request receptor: (Class) model;` ? (keyword `id` missing)

Comment: Yes, a warning, sorry.

Comment: Yes, fixed that. The cast solves this, thanks. Also, if I change the id<Response> for id the problems goes away, I'm intrigued why.

Answer (score 0):

These warning is because  your `RequestExecutor`'s `execute:` method returns an object of a general `id<Response>` type. The variables, however, are declared as `ListUsersResponse *` so the compiler expects a more specific type (and it isn't sure if that type cast is correct or not, it has no way of knowing).

---

You can get rid of the warning by either:

a) Declaring your variables with `id<Response>` type instead of `ListUsersRequest *` type like:

```
id<Response> result = [RequestExecutor execute:request receptor:[ListUsersResponse class]];
```

Or

b) Casting them on the fly (if you are sure that at that point they will be of the appropriate class):

```
ListUsersResponse *result = (ListUsersRequest *)[RequestExecutor execute:request receptor:[ListUsersResponse class]];
```

Comment: Declaring result as id<Response> the DataResponse conforming methods are lost.

Comment: They would be "lost" in the same way as you loose the ListUserResponse. You can cast them to "get them back".